# Compound calculation of GCP GCE SLAs based on number of instances?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

GCP publishes a 99.99% uptime SLA for GCE.

How would I calculate an estimated SLA if my application used services deployed on 1,000 GCE instances? Assuming that the services were dependent on each other, would the estimated downtime per year of my application be 1,000 * 0.0001 = 0.10 or 10% per year?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question as defined in SO guidelines but rather a Cloud provider-specific pricing question

Answer (score 1):

SLA is not for only one VM instance, as per official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/sla)

> "For virtual machine instances: Loss of external connectivity or
>   persistent disk access for all running Instances, when Instances are
>   placed across two or more Zones in the same Region."

So SLA will meant if a specific zone goes down for .01% of the month, that would be like 4:38 minutes, avg.